# How do I set the read timeout for a specific query in the C# driver?

Tags: .net, cassandra, datastax-csharp-driver

**Problem**

I would like to set a timeout for a specific readonly query using the dotnet driver.

**Context**

I have a query like`select count(*) from TABLE where ID=value`

I am aware that:

- count(*) queries are not efficient
- there is no guarantee that that query will return correct results
- it will make full cluster scan

Despite all this, I still want to run that query once every 3-4 months.

Requirements:

- specify the timeout from the dotnet driver
- do not touch any cassandra server yml configuration

**What I have tries**
I have big database locally on a single node. When I set a timeout to the query it is respected and everything works. In several minutes I got results. However, when I have a cluster of 5 nodes, a coordinator node gets the query and executes it against the other nodes and it hits 5 seconds timeout. Any timeouts which I have configured throught the driver for the socket or for the query are ignored. I also tried with all possible consistency levels. Also tried to use retry policy which ignores the errors.

[Elders/Cronus.Persistence.Cassandra](https://github.com/Elders/Cronus.Persistence.Cassandra/blob/preview/src/Elders.Cronus.Persistence.Cassandra/Preview/IndexByEventTypeStore.cs#L95)

**Question**
Is it possible to set a timeout for a readonly query through the dotnet driver when cassandra is configured in a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The client-side read timeout is configured with [`SocketOptions.SetReadTimeoutMillis()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.16/api/Cassandra.SocketOptions.html#Cassandra_SocketOptions_SetReadTimeoutMillis_System_Int32_) which by default is set to `12000` ms (12s).

You can override the timeout for a specific operation by calling [`Statement.SetReadTimeoutMillis()`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.16/api/Cassandra.Statement.html#Cassandra_Statement_SetReadTimeoutMillis_System_Int32_) which is shared with all other statement types.

As a side note, a `COUNT()` is perfectly fine when the query is restricted to a single partition since it will simply count the rows within that partition. It won't cause a full table scan and doesn't suffer from the problems I discussed in [Why `COUNT()` is bad in Cassandra](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314567/). Cheers!

Comment: I have tried this but this works when the query is executed against single node cassandra setup. In a cluster it timesout after 5 sec. https://github.com/Elders/Cronus.Persistence.Cassandra/blob/preview/src/Elders.Cronus.Persistence.Cassandra/CassandraProvider.cs#L77

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, the 5-second timeout sounds like the default value of `read_request_timeout`.  So I would bet that this is getting cut off at the cluster level, regardless of what gets set for the driver config.

Have a look at your Cassandra nodes in the `cassandra.yaml` file for this value: `read_request_timeout`.  It should be set to `5000ms`.

Be careful in raising that too high.  That value was picked for a reason, and ultimately is there to protect the cluster from queries that consume too many resources.

Comment: Exactly, however, I do not want to touch the cassandra.yaml file and control this through the driver only when executing that query.